# Is it possible to submit the app with dynamic lib to Appstore for iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store, dylib, dynamic-library

Apple supports dynamic library (.dylib) from iOS 8 [ iphone/ipad app ].  My research shows that if we use "dlopen" [ void* dylibLink = dlopen(dylibPath, RTLD_NOW); ] method Apple will reject our app.

If anyone has successfully submitted an app with a dynamic lib, could you please help me with the steps?